# Active multiple browsers windows at once

Tags: windows, browser

I am working on a project where i want to use 4 browser windows active at once but the problem is when i click on 1 window the other windows get unactive. So kindly help me what should i do, I have tried to find many ways but didn't work. I hope you understand my problem.

I am using INCOGNITION BROWSER.
In Windows 10

I have tried using softwares and scripts for making active multiple browser windows at once.

I want to make 4 windows active at once